# How to check that a variable has the same value for all agents?

Tags: netlogo

I am sure this is a rookie question, but I am still getting used to NetLogo so please pardon me.

I am using a variable I created for a breed as a flag.  If all breeds have the same value for the variable, I consider my flag ON and I take certain action.  How can I check that a variable has the same value for all agents/breeds in NetLogo?

For example:

```
breeds-own [ flagvariable ]
```

How can I check that for ALL breeds `flagvariable = 1`?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than having `flagvariable` be a breeds-own variable, it should be turtles-own variable, since it's shared by all turtles. Then, you can use [`all?`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#all) to check if all turtles have it set to a certain value:

```
all? turtles [ flagvariable = 1]
```

Alternatively, if you don't care what the value is, you can use [`remove-duplicates`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#remove-duplicates) to make sure that they all have the same value:

```
length remove-duplicates [ flagvariable ] of turtles = 1
```

Here, we're counting how many different values of `flagvariable` there currently are. If it's exactly 1, then we know all turtles share the same value.

Comment: Thank you.  This seems to work.  However, I now realize that my model does not repeat.  It appears my procedures in the go procedure just executes once, then after tick #1, the go procedure no longer executes, but the tick counter continues to increase.  Strange.  Any insights as to what could create this kind of "go procedure frozen" situation?

Thank you.

Comment: Glad the answer helped you. Make sure it mark as correct as that helps people know which questions have been satisfactorily answered.

Concerning your new question, I would definitely need more information (including code snippets). That said, you should open a new question on stackoverflow rather than asking it in the comments here.